# Problem installing a ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I downloaded setup.exe, and then begin to install and it immediately crashes.

On win7 it worked fine.  On XP it doesn't work.

[image]

Error text:

> Unable to install or run the
>   application. The application requires
>   that assemble stdole Version
>   7.0.3300.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

Comment: Check this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/43398969-4228-41d7-a792-8dd66472b79f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include stdole.dll as a required file in your Publish settings in Visual Studio.  Once you publish your app again, it should then include that file in your app when it's installed.

More info can be found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/610601-requires-stdole-version-7-0-33-installed-gac-clickonce-deployment).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to a few people that i had to install a click once application i developed. Basically something happened in their installation of .NET and the needed .DLL's were not moved to the GAC. It's very simple to fix, basically You need to copy stdole.dll from C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\ to C:\Windows\Assembly ... that should fix your issue. Including them in the application isn't the best idea, this will fix it for ALL click once applications rather then just that one you are currently building.

P.S. Dragging the files to the location will work, you might get an error if you try to copy it.

Comment: you propose to do this all the users of my program? not the best option.

Comment: not the best option for wide spread use, however if its just for you or what not then it's okay. If you know it's not going to work on the others PCs then including the file in your app would be a better choice, but otherwise as long as the end users installation went okay then including the file would be redundant.